# AWK to print columns based on the columns summation

Tags: printing, awk

I have a file that has numeric values in the form of a matrix. I have written an awk script that prints the header, then adds 1 to the columns 'sum' if the values in the columns are less than 5 and greater than 0. Then, at the end, it prints the sum of each column. This part works fine:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS=OFS=" "}
  NR==1 {print}
  NR>1  {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i < 5 && $i > 0) a[i]+=1}
  END   {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf $a[i]
}' snp_fake2.txt > tmp.txt`
```

My goal is to print the entire column if that columns sum is greater than some value THRESHOLD. I have tried adding an if statement after the second for loop to determine if the columns sum, a[i], is > THRESHOLD, and then printing the column:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS=OFS=" "}
  NR==1 {print}
  NR>1  {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i < 5 && $i > 0) a[i]+=1}
  END   {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (a[i] < THRESHOLD) printf $i
}' snp_fake2.txt > tmp.txt`
```

But when I run this the script does not output the entire column, only a single number. **How can I print the entire column instead of just the single value?**

Comment: (1) Your use of the word “sum” is misleading.  You are dealing with the ***count*** of values that meet criteria.  (2) I believe that I sort-of understand what you want, but it would help if you would show an example of input and the output that you want to get from it. … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWK processes the file one line at a time. It has no memory of previous lines. The END rule executes after the last line is processed. At this point AWK cannot print all the entries in column $i because it only knows a single value for column $i: the one from the last line.

Your goal requires two passes of the file: one to calculate the column sum, and a second to print out the entire column (for the appropriate columns). To do so, you could write a shell script that calls awk to calculate the sums, and then calls awk (or something else) to print the columns.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, one way is to use two dimensional array. It works with GNU awk.

```
echo -e '1 4 7\n2 5 8\n3 6 9' | awk '
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        field[i][NR]=$i
        if ($i < 5 && $i > 0) {
            a[i]+=1
            }
        }
}
END {
    for (i in a) {
        if (a[i] > 2) {
            for (j in field[i]) print field[i][j]
            }
        }
}'
```